# Zend Framework (500 Internal Server Error) on Shared Host

Tags: zend-framework

I am using a typical  Zend framework installation on a shared host where I can't change the rootDirectory. And I am facing the well known problem of (redirecting all requests to **/public** folder).

My problem is a bit different. It is as follows:

- www.xyz.com/book/list  ==> works fine
- www.xyz.com/book/view/id/3 ==>  500 Internal server Error !!

Any idea what might be the problem ?!

Best Regards,

Tariq

Comment: I usually start these investigations wondering what is wrong with my hosting setup.  Then, I find out it's my own code.  Anyways, it's hard to help you without seeing all pertinent code.  All the best.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess code?

Answer (score 0):

It's probable that there's something wrong with the rewrite settings in .htaccess

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but it is not the .htaccess.

Comment: BTW, the same configuration works fine on my localhost running on Windows XP !!